# Let $a$ be a natural number not divisible by $5$

Tags: number-theory, induction, divisibility

Let $a$ be a natural number not divisible by $5$

Prove that $8a^{8n}+a^{4n}-4$ is a multiple of $5$ for

all n natural number.

My try :

Using induction

Let  :  $ A=8a^{8n}+a^{4n}-4$

For n=0 then A=8+1-4=0=0\mod 5$ $->$ true

For : n+1

$A=8a^{8n+8}+a^{4n+4}-4$

But I don't know how I complete

Comment: Is it an exercise on induction or was that simply the method  you first thought to try?

Answer (score 3):

Hint :
\begin{eqnarray*}
a^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}
\end{eqnarray*}
if $a \not \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$.

Comment: Sir can u explain plz why \begin{eqnarray*}
a^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Either look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem or just calculate $1^4,2^4,3^4,4^4$ modulo $5$.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$8a^{8n}+a^{4n}-4=5a^{8n}+(a^{4n}-1)(3a^{4n}+4)$$
Proof that $5\vert(a^{4n}-1)$

Other way, Suppose that $a=5p+q$ with $p=0,1,2,3,\cdots $ and $q=1,2,3,4$. Then  $$a^4=625 p^4 + 500 p^3 q + 150 p^2 q^2 + 20 p q^3 + q^4$$
How $q=1,2,3,4\implies q^4=1,16,81,256$ then $a^4=5k+1$ then 
   $a^{4n}=(5k+1)^n\implies a^{4n}-1=(5k+1)^n-1=(5k+1-1)[(5k+1)^{n-1}+(5k+1)^{n-2}+\cdots+1]=5k[(5k+1)^{n-1}+(5k+1)^{n-2}+\cdots+1]$

Comment: But how I can prove $a^{4n}-1$ multiple of 5 ?

Comment: See the other answer

Comment: See answer one, Other way, Suposse that $a=5p+q$ with $p=0,1,2,3,\cdots $ and $q=1,2,3,4$.... See the new edition